# Avoid resolution of invalid hostname to default ip

Tags: 16.04, networking, 18.04, dhcp, systemd-resolved

When connecting to my internet provider's box with Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04, any invalid hostname is resolved to some kind of default IP (`82.216.111.26` which is fact is the ip of `numericable.fr`).

Example:

`$ getent hosts invalidhostname
82.216.111.26   numericable.fr`

When I launch the same command from any other network (after having run `systemd-resolve --flush-caches` in order to flush the hostname resolution caches), nothing is returned, which is logic.

I suppose that it is a bad DHCP setting from my internet provider (SFR), that makes `systemd-resolved` to add `domain numericable.fr` at the beginning of `/etc/resolv.conf`

Is there a way to deactivate this strange behavior?

Comment: That's a DNS hijacking that is sometimes done by your ISP.  It can be blocked through doing a `bogus-nxdomain`.  See:  https://www.cambus.net/nxdomain-hijacking-dnsmasq-to-the-rescue/  Also another good one to see is https://hackercodex.com/guide/how-to-stop-isp-dns-server-hijacking/